# Closures not updating local variables

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire

How can I update local variables inside a Alamofire closure?

I am trying to update a count of the # of msgs successfully sent using an Alamofire Request. The obvious place to do this is inside the closure - in the .success case.

So I am trying to update a local variable within the closure, but its scope it limited to inside the closure. I see the local updating when I step into the closure. But when I examine it below the closure, its value it 0. Hence the print() displays 'SENT 0 of n RECORDS.' I suspect it is because it falls through the loop before the closure is called.

Questions:
1) What am I missing? 
2) I don't understand the completion() call. I can't find that method in my code. Is it a placeholder which I replace with my callback?

```
func uploadSavedPacketsToServer(completion: @escaping (Int, Int) -> Void) {

var totalNumRecsToSend = recordsToSend.count
for (i, currentRec) in recordsToSend.enumerated() {

   // build request....

    Alamofire.request(request)
             .validate()
             .responseJSON { response in

             switch response.result {

             case .success:
                  // pass the # of recs remaining as well as total # of recs to send
                   completion( (totalNumRecsToSend - i),totalNumRecsToSend)

             case .failure(let error):
                   print("SUBMIT failure: \(error)")

                  // -1, 0 indicates a unique error. Parsed in completion handler
                   completion(-1, 0)   
             }
     }   // end closure
   }   // end for all records to send
}


// Executed AFTER the network call has returned!!
let completionHandler: (Int, Int) -> Void = { (numSent, numTotal) in

error checking ....
    if (numTotal - numSent == 0) {
        // SUCCESS
        // keep a running count of # packets sent to server in this period
        ServerConstants.numPktsUploaded += numSent
    }

    // Build the Notification
    // 1) Create the body content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Data Upload", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: strMsg, arguments: nil)

     // 2) Configure the trigger to appear 10 minutes from now. NOTE: using Calendar will accomodate for DST, TZs etc.
     var calendar = Calendar.current
     let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .timeZone],
                     from: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1)), repeats: false)

     // 3) Create the Local Notification object
     let notify = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "DataUpload", content: content, trigger: trigger)

     // 4) and queue it up
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notify, withCompletionHandler: nil)

     // reset our pkt counter
     ServerConstants.numPktsUploaded = 0             

     // and the time of our last upload
     ServerConstants.lastNotifyTime = currentTime    
     return
}
```

Comment: "What am I missing" You are missing what "asynchronous" means. It means you are printing _before_ you have set the numRecsSent! I've written a blog post to help you: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: @matt thanks for the link. I have a better handle on it now. I edited my question to include the working code. I'm sure there are still problems, but it is much closer than my original post. If you post your comment as an Answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DispatchGroup` to be notified when all asynchronous requests finish

```
let g = DispatchGroup() /// <<<<< 1

for (i, currentRec) in recordsToSend.enumerated() {

    // build request....

    g.enter()  /// <<<<< 2

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success:
                // pass the server's response back in 1st param, & error status in 2nd param
                completion(response.value, nil)

                // keep count of how many records were successfully sent
                self.setNumRecsSent()

            case .failure(let error):
                print("SUBMIT failure: \(error)")
                completion(nil, response.error)

            }

            g.leave()  /// <<<<< 3

    }   // end closure
}   // end for all records to send


g.notify(queue: .main) {  /// <<<<< 4

    print("SENT \(self.getNumRecsSent()) of \(numRecsToSend) RECORDS: ")

}
```